# add module in qt(QML module)

Tags: qt, module, qml

how can i add these modules in qt

QtQuick Controls 1.4
 QtQuick Controls Styles 1.4
 QtQuick Extras 1.4
 QtQuick Extras Private 1.0
they are not installed in my qt creator 
thanks

Comment: Not installed in your QtCreator or in your Qt installation? How do you realize that?